# Drop-Down Cascade Issue: How to cascade two drop down

Tags: asp.net, database, vb.net, entity-framework, drop-down-menu

I am trying to cascade dropdowns using  ASP and VB

```
1st drop down   --> Sex Type
                            > Male
                            > Female
2nd Drop Down   -->Status
                            > Orphan
                            > Married
                            > UnMarried
                            > Divorced
                            > Widow
                            > Special Need
                            > Normal
```

Now,
If Male selected from 1st drop down, then select (Orphan, Special Need, Married, UnMarried,  Divorced, Widow and Normal) from 2nd Drop Down

And if Female selected from 1st drop down, then select (Orphan, Special Need and Normal) from 2nd Drop Down

I am getting data of drop dwons from database using Entities;

**VB Code**

```
context As New EGrantsModel.Entities

ddlSexType.DataSource = context.SEXTYPE
ddlSexType.DataValueField = "SEXTYPE"
ddlSexType.DataTextField = "SEXTYPE"
ddlSexType.DataBind()

ddlCitizenStatus.DataSource = context.CITIZENSTATUS
ddlCitizenStatus.DataValueField = "CITIZENSTATUSID"
ddlCitizenStatus.DataTextField = "CITIZENSTATUS"
ddlCitizenStatus.DataBind()
```

**ASP Code**

```
<div class="labelinput">
 <asp:Label ID="lblSexType" CssClass="lblwidth" runat="server" Text="">Sex Type</asp:Label>
 <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSexType" runat="server"/>
   </div>

 <div class="labelinput">
   <asp:Label ID="lblCitizenStatus" CssClass="lblwidth" runat="server" Text="">Status</asp:Label>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCitizenStatus" runat="server"/>
     </div>
```

Can any one guide me in this regards. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this:

```
Public Class WebForm4
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Private Sub CitizenBind(ByVal strSexType As String)

        Dim lstCitizenStatus As New List(Of CitizenStatus)

        With lstCitizenStatus
            .Add(New CitizenStatus("1", "Orphan"))
            .Add(New CitizenStatus("2", "Married"))
            .Add(New CitizenStatus("3", "UnMarried"))
            .Add(New CitizenStatus("4", "Divorced"))
            .Add(New CitizenStatus("5", "Widow"))
            .Add(New CitizenStatus("6", "Special Need"))
            .Add(New CitizenStatus("7", "Normal"))
        End With

        Me.ddlCitizenStatus.Items.Clear()

        With Me.ddlCitizenStatus
            .DataSource = lstCitizenStatus
            .DataValueField = "CitizenStatusId"
            .DataTextField = "CitizenStatusT"
            .DataBind()
        End With

        If strSexType.Contains("F") Then

            Dim lstCitizenStatusRemove As New List(Of CitizenStatus)
            With lstCitizenStatusRemove
                .Add(New CitizenStatus("2", "Married"))
                .Add(New CitizenStatus("3", "UnMarried"))
                .Add(New CitizenStatus("4", "Divorced"))
                .Add(New CitizenStatus("5", "Widow"))
            End With

            For Each lstCS As CitizenStatus In lstCitizenStatusRemove
                Me.ddlCitizenStatus.Items.Remove(New ListItem(lstCS.CitizenStatusT.ToString(), lstCS.CitizenStatusId.ToString()))
            Next

        End If

    End Sub

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        If Not Page.IsPostBack Then

            Dim lstSexType As New List(Of SexType)
            lstSexType.Add(New SexType("Male"))
            lstSexType.Add(New SexType("Female"))

            With Me.ddlSexType
                .DataSource = lstSexType
                .DataValueField = "SexTypeT"
                .DataTextField = "SexTypeT"
                .DataBind()
            End With

            CitizenBind("ALL")

        End If

    End Sub

    Protected Sub ddlSexType_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles ddlSexType.SelectedIndexChanged

        CitizenBind(Me.ddlSexType.SelectedValue)

    End Sub

End Class
```

If you have any questions about the code please let me know.

Comment: Thanks a lot CoderRoller for your kind and generous reply, it really helps me and just to inform that how I solved my problem, my answer is below, but I accept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

On the Selected index change event of ddlSexType bind the 2nd drop down.
Check the selected item in 1st drop down if it is equal to Male then bind the corresponding items.
Example:

```
protected void ddlSexType_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
   if( ddlSexType.Text == "Male" )
   {
     // Bind 2nd drop down
     // you can add items manually as 
      ListItem li = new ListItem();
      li.Text = "Orphan";

      ddlCitizenStatus.Items.Add(li);
      // Add all the items in the same way

    // or get data from the database and bind it to the dropdown

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    ddlCitizenStatus.DataSource = dt;
    ddlCitizenStatus.DataTextFeild= "DataFeild";
    ddlCitizenStatus.DataValueFeild= "DataValueFeild";
    ddlCitizenStatus.DataBind();
   }
   else if( ddlSexType.Text == "Female" )
  {
       // Bind other items
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this is not the exact case. I am trying to filter the data as well when selecting male.

Comment: @AbdulAziz ok. The data which will you bind for the second drop down is present in a single table and you want to filter them ?

Comment: Yes, this what I want to accomplish. I mean that If I select "Female", then its fine to select all items in table, But if I select "Male" it filters only some items. I really appreciate your kind help.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved my problem

I just add three fields in my table

```
1- ISMALE

2- ISFEMALE

3- COMMON
```

And make `COMMON` **True** if both male and female statuses are in common.

And make `ISMALE` **True** and ISFEMALE **False** for male statuses.

And make `ISFEMALE` **True** and ISMALE **False** for female statuses.

**VB Code**

```
Protected Sub ddlSexType_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ddlSexType.SelectedIndexChanged
    Try

        Dim context As New EGrantsModel.Entities
        If (ddlSexType.SelectedValue = "Female") Then
            Dim femaleDataSource As Object
            femaleDataSource = (From femaleDS In context.CITIZENSTATUS _
                                Where femaleDS.ISFEMALE = "1" And femaleDS.ISMALE = "0" AndAlso femaleDS.COMMON = "1"
                                Select femaleDS)
            ddlCitizenStatus.DataSource = femaleDataSource
            ddlCitizenStatus.DataValueField = "CITIZENSTATUSID"
            ddlCitizenStatus.DataTextField = "CITIZENSTATUS"
            ddlCitizenStatus.DataBind()
        ElseIf (ddlSexType.SelectedValue = "Male") Then
            Dim maleDataSource As Object
            maleDataSource = (From femaleDS In context.CITIZENSTATUS _
                                Where femaleDS.ISFEMALE = "0" And femaleDS.ISMALE = "1" AndAlso femaleDS.COMMON = "1"
                                Select femaleDS)
            ddlCitizenStatus.DataSource = maleDataSource
            ddlCitizenStatus.DataValueField = "CITIZENSTATUSID"
            ddlCitizenStatus.DataTextField = "CITIZENSTATUS"
            ddlCitizenStatus.DataBind()
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        callErrorPage(ex.Message, ex.InnerException)
    End Try
End Sub
```

I am really new to VB, so if someone think that this a lengthy approach then kindly update me for a better approach.

Thanks again to **Waqar Janjua** and **CoderRoller** for their valuable time and expertise.